# Robots.txt is not accessible for Opencart website

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, robots.txt

When you enter example.com/robots.txt, my opencart website giving me 404 error like

[image: Error]

It should work like https://www.daraz.pk/robots.txt Please help.

Comment: Did you upload it?

Comment: yes, robots.txt is uploaded on server

Comment: Do you see the request in the access logs? Is there a .htaccess file or web server config that has an excessive rewrite?

Comment: No, I've seen this and there is no error or rewrite.

Comment: This is rule that placed in .htaccess file for robots.txt # Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Answer (score 0):

It was permission issue and my file permission was o770, when I change this this 777 and it works for me.

Comment: You should never use 777 permissions as it leaves your files open to modification your scripts are vulnerable. Instead, the contents only need to readable by the web server user, so 755 if it's a directory or 644 if it's a file.